# Sudo do not ask for passwords if NOPASSWD doesn't work

Tags: ssh, sudo

I've got a program that runs once and removes itself from `sudoers` when finished.  And I've got some scripts that call that function from an `ssh` session.  What I'd like is for these commands not to hang up at the password prompt when the command I want to run is not in `sudoers`.

Is there a way to override the `SUDO_ASKPASS` function to just bomb out so I can skip running things that would otherwise present me with password prompts?

My best attempt was something like:

```
SUDO_ASKPASS=/bin/false sudo -A /opt/sbin/mycommand
```

but it left me with

```
sudo: pam_authenticate: Conversation error
```

I basically want `sudo` to never prompt me for a password regardless of whether the command I'm running is in sudoers.

My lazybones fix is to remove the `-t` from my `ssh` command and hope that I never need to actually use the terminal.

Another fix, I guess, would be just to toast my script that is in `sudoers` and make it print an ASCII thumbs-up or something useful.

Is there a straightforward way around this?

Answer (score 1):

You can ask `sudo -l`. It returns either the full path of the command to be executed, or it exits with non-zero status. Here, we ignore the output and check the status return:

```
if sudo -l somecommand... >/dev/null
then
    echo "This is permitted" >&2
else
    echo "You are out of luck today" >&2
fi
```